# How to show only the active desktop's applications in the taskbar? (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: gnome, 19.04, workspaces, window-manager, panel

I'm trying to work with workspaces in Ubuntu 19.04 but I can't figure how to show only active apps on a deskop in the taskbar. I open Firefox in workspace 1, then change to workspace 2 and click the Firefox icon again but instead of opening a new instace on Firefox for that workspace 2 it does redirect me to the one running on workspace 1.

I've searched and found some people got it working in Lubuntu by:

> Right click the taskbar, click 'Configure "Task manager"', and enable
>   "Show only windows from desktop 'Current'".

I'm trying to find something like this in Ubuntu 19.04 but nothing happens when right clicking on the taskbar. Searched in Settings too but found nothing about this. Can anyone help me with this please? Any system setting, app or extension to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For me, at least, it was easier to configure these options using a GUI for `dconf`, called `dconf-editor`.

You should be able to install it using

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

For the default dock in Ubuntu you can navigate to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/` and change the options `isolate-monitors` and `isolate-workspaces`, which should reproduce the behaviour you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by install `dconf`

```
sudo apt install dconf
```

After installing it search for `isolate-workspaces` and turn that setting on.

There is also an extension called `Launch new instance` [download link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/600/launch-new-instance/) which will launch a new instance each time, I personally don't prefer this and don't use it but just in case you want that.

*Hope it helps.*